# Inserting last two digits from column into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

So I'm supposed to take the last two digits from the phone number, and insert it into a new column in the same table.

I'm currently getting this error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Pass_id', table 'lunches.dbo.passenger'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

This is the query I'm using to get this error:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.passenger (age)
SELECT 
RIGHT(phone, 2)
FROM dbo.passenger
```

Comment: the last 2 digits of the phone number are their age? wtf?

Comment: As the error **clearly** says - you **must** provide a value for the `pass_id` column! You cannot insert just the `age` column. Also: what **datatypes** are your `phone` and `age` columns? If `phone` is a `varchar`, then the `RIGHT(...)` will also be a `varchar`

Comment: You are not passing a value for the column `Pass_id`, which can't be `NULL`

Comment: @MitchWheat yeah, of course, that's how it works, didn't you know?

Comment: Do you really mean to do an `INSERT` (add new rows to the table) or an `UPDATE` (change the value of the new age column for existing rows)?

Comment: LOL! it's a school assignment. "The age of each passenger is the last 2 digits of their phone number. Insert all passenger ages."

IT'S NOT MY IDEA OKAY!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.passenger
SET    age = Cast(Right(phone, 2) As tinyint)
WHERE  phone IS NOT NULL
AND    Right(phone, 2) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: ... `WHERE phone is not null`

Comment: To echo previous comments: No idea why you'd want to set the age to the last 2 digits of a phone number, but hey...

Comment: Wild guess - they're re-using an obsolete column (age) for something new (extension).  If so, it's a terrible idea and a firing offense in many places.

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure why i was using an insert. i changed the code up a bit myself though. the phone number was char and the age was integer. i changed it to be the same datatype, and this is the query i used:
UPDATE dbo.passenger SET age = RIGHT(phone, 2)
and that worked.

Comment: @CodyRobinson so your "age" column is now `char`? Do you really think that this is good practice? Phone numbers are different as they really are textual (e.g. they can have leading zeroes).

Comment: yes they are both char. it's just for coursework, nothing serious or real world. i know it's not good practice, but i'm just trying to finish this class up so i don't have to deal with sql anymore! thank you for your help though.